# flot bar chart with equal distance x axis

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using flot for my reports. I can get my data into flot, but I am confused about the formatting of it.

For example, my flot code looks like this:

```
var views = [
   [3747, 7],
   [3119, 2],
   [3442, 2],
   [3748, 1],
   [3754, 1],
   [2645, 1],
   [3534, 1],
   [3120, 1],
   [2836, 1],
   [3571, 1]
];
var ticks = [
    3747,
    3119,
    3442,
    3748,
    3754,
    2645,
    3534,
    3120,
    2836,
    3571
];
var options = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable:true,
        clickable:true,
        tickColor:"#dddddd",
        borderWidth:0
    },
    bars: {
        align: "center",
        barWidth: 0.5
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: ticks
    },
    colors:["#FA5833"]
};
var data = [{data: views, label: "Views"}];
var placeholder = $("#top-views-graph");
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

which shows this:

[image]

I have two problems with this.

1. The x axis is automatically adjusting the gaps between each label. I want them all to be equal.
2. I need the actual bars to extend the full width of the "grid column"

does anyone know how to achieve this?

I have tried the documentation and google but I can't seem to find anyway to do it.
I would have thought it is something that a lot of people require.

Any help would be appreciated :)

/r3plica

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flot is taking your tick values as numeric (give me a tick at this number) when what you really want is for them to just be labels.

Specify your ticks and data like this:

```
var views = [[0,7],
             [1,2],
             [2,2],
             [3,1],
             [4,1],
             [5,1],
             [6,1],
             [7,1],
             [8,1],
             [9,1]];


    var ticks = [
        [0,'3747'],
        [1,'3119'],
        [2,'3442'],
        [3,'3748'],
        [4,'3754'],
        [5,'2645'],
        [6,'3534'],
        [7,'3120'],
        [8,'2836'],
        [9,'3571']
    ];
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XMH5T/).

[image]